# Angular nested *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having a table with two nested iterations, the first three columns where an array of object (item) iterates, and a fourth column is where an array of numbers should iterate ( `total=[30,70,100]` )

```
<table class="table"> 
    <thead class="thead-dark"> 
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Amount</th>    
        </tr>        
    </thead>

    <tbody>        
        <tr *ngFor="let i of item">  

            <td>{{i.product}}</td>
            <td>{{i.price}}</td>
            <td>{{i.quantity}}</td>

            <ng-container *ngFor="let t of total">
                <td>{{t}}</td>
            </ng-container>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The object array iterates fine, however, the problem is with the array of numbers ( `total=[30,70,100]` ), I tried to place the (`ng-container *ngFor="let t of total"`) on different levels, but it always getting populated in a wrong way, I would appreciate advising me how to solve it.

Comment: I assume you want to display total for total just for a single product. The total array is stored separately from item array. Does indexes match for both the array?

Comment: Actually the total array is stored separately from item array, so indexes don't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `index` level for the arrays are same, you can always use the `index` to track and repeat the element.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let i of item; let in=index">

  <td>{{i.product}}</td>
  <td>{{i.price}}</td>
  <td>{{i.quantity}}</td>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let t of total[in]">
    <td>{{t}}</td>
  </ng-container>

</tr>
```

**Edit:** If the OP is multiplying quantity with price to come up with total then we don't need to maintain a separate array for that, we can just multiply it in the view and get it:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let i of item; let in=index">

  <td>{{i.product}}</td>
  <td>{{i.price}}</td>
  <td>{{i.quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{i.price * i.quantity}}</td>


</tr>
```

Comment: The total array is stored separately, so indexes are not matching

Comment: @Adel, how do you expect to map them with the products then?

Comment: I don't map them, I'm multiplying each price with the quantity to come up with the total price for each product, to be printed out as an invoice, the ts file code is like this:                                       this.service.getSalesItems(data.id).subscribe(data=>{
        this.item=data
        data.findIndex(d=>{
             
          this.total.push(d.price*d.quantity)
         
        })
      })

Comment: @Adel ,you don't have to maintain a separate array to show total then, just do it in the view like above edit

Comment: the result was like this:  30 * 10  in the table

Comment: @Adel, sorry for the typo, do it like above

Comment: Many thanks @Sunil,  I made a funciton takes two parameters, parse into float and return the result ...<td>{{ totalValue(i.price, i.quantity) }} </td>

Answer (score 0):

We may need more information on how the data should be populated, what I can see is that the td tag is repeating in a wrong way when iterates with the total, having more tds than th tags. Also the total variable is a property inside the item or is separated?. For now I can give you examples for some scenarios:

If you want to have the total in a single td and the total is a property of i

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of item">  

  <td>{{i.product}}</td>
  <td>{{i.price}}</td>
  <td>{{i.quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{i.total.join(,)}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you want to have the total in a single td and the total is just a variable outside the item array.

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of item let index = index">  

  <td>{{i.product}}</td>
  <td>{{i.price}}</td>
  <td>{{i.quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{total[index]}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you want to have sum the total in a single td and the total is a property of i

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of item">  

  <td>{{i.product}}</td>
  <td>{{i.price}}</td>
  <td>{{i.quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{i.total.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you want to have sum the total in a single td and the total is just a variable outside the item array.

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of item let index = index">  

  <td>{{i.product}}</td>
  <td>{{i.price}}</td>
  <td>{{i.quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{total[index].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: this.service.getSalesItems(data.id).subscribe(data=>{
        this.item=data
        data.findIndex(d=>{
          
          this.total.push(d.price*d.quantity)
          
        })
      })

Comment: shall I do it : {{total[index].reduce((i.price, i.quantity)=>{ i.price * i.quantity, 0 })}}

Comment: I solved the problem by making function takes two parameters parse them into float, and return the result, <td> {{totalValue(i.price, i.quantity) }} <td/> , so thank you for your contribution